# Python 3.6. Запуск программы с обменом данных

Tags: python, сокет

На энтузиазме делаю сервер используя библиотеку сокетов на python 3.6. Возникла острая потребность для моего проекта запуска всех процессов принятия подключения клиента и отправляемой им информации на фоне, не затормаживая основной код программы, да так, что бы основной код программы мог обрабатывать это все в свободное для него время. *То есть я хочу что бы при подключении клиента, и принятии от него данных, основной код не тормозил на inf количество времени, т.к при принятии подключения код не продолжится, пока подключение не будет получено, и при принятии даты, код не продолжится, пока не будет получена дата.* Слышал о мульти процессинге, но не совсем подходит, ведь процесс не переключится на другой, пока, опять же, сокет не получит подключение с клиентом ( В виде исполнения кода принятия клиента, я думаю, там что то вроде while процесса, который не заканчивается без подключения ).*Если бы удалось сделать запуск отдельной программы на фоне, которая будет закидывать данными основную программу, то можно было бы не тормозить основной код, который будет обрабатывать эти данные в свободный момент времени.*

Comment: `select.select`

Comment: вы хотите узнать как основной цикл сервера реализуется? Если это не образовательная задача, то лучше на более высоком уровне работать. К примеру, можно [flask библиотеку](http://flask.pocoo.org/) использовать, чтобы веб-приложение создать. Если для образования хотите узнать как параллельный ввод/вывод организовать, то рекомендую видео [David Beazley - Python Concurrency From the Ground Up: LIVE! - PyCon 2015](https://youtu.be/MCs5OvhV9S4)

Comment: "свободное время" - это несколько расплывчатое понятие. мы не знаем деталей Вашего проекта, без них вопрос несколько теоретический. может Вам проще постоянно принимать/отправлять данные и хранить их в БД, тогда пользователь не нужно ждать сетевого обмена, например...